# Performance issue on rending large number of markers and polylines in Google Map

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Render a large number of simple (two point) polylines with markers on a map getting performance issue. To place 30,000 markers and 15,000 simple polylines, it’s taking time to render.

Could anyone advise on the best way to achieve this?